# SQL Server and blocked transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I have a question about SQL Server and transactions.
My application use transactions and I use snapshot isolation level.
My problem is that sometimes, for specific SQL statements the execution in different transactions will be blocked.
I don't want to commit the transactions because the transaction durations are related to users decision.

In a transactions I insert a record into a table:

```
INSERT INTO "SEED"."SETS" WITH (ROWLOCK)
  ("SECT_ID", "SET_ID", "META_SET_ID", "SET_ROW")
VALUES (1838, 89405, 158, 27);
```

and in another transaction I execute a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO "SEED"."CELLS" WITH (ROWLOCK) ("SET_ID", "META_CELL_ID")  
SELECT "TARGET_SET_ID", "CELLS"."META_CELL_ID"
        FROM "SEED"."TT_T_SET_1C8BFA4C_7058"
        INNER JOIN "SEED"."CELLS" ON ("CELLS"."SET_ID"="TT_T_SET_1C8BFA4C_7058"."SOURCE_SET_ID")
        ORDER BY "TARGET_SET_ID"`
```

The amount of inserted rows could be thousands.

"CELLS" table is a child of "SETS" table (1 to n relation over "SET_ID" field).
On "SETS" there is an unique non clustered index on "SET_ID" called "SETS_U01".
In "CELLS" there is a clustered index on "SET_ID" called "IX_CELLS_F01".

If i execute the second query the Sql Server engine will be blocked on "SETS_U01" **Index Scan** even if the transactions was created in snapshot isolation.

If i execute the second query with a batch like this:

```
DECLARE @rowCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "SEED"."TT_T_SET_1C8BFA4C_7058"
    INNER JOIN "SEED"."CELLS" ON ("CELLS"."SET_ID"="TT_T_SET_1C8BFA4C_7058"."SOURCE_SET_ID"))
    DECLARE @batchSize INT = 2000 
    DECLARE @startIndex INT = 0 
    WHILE @startIndex < @rowCount 
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO "SEED"."CELLS" WITH (ROWLOCK) ("SET_ID", "META_CELL_ID") 
            SELECT "TARGET_SET_ID", "META_CELL_ID" 
            FROM ( SELECT "TARGET_SET_ID", "META_CELL_ID", ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (ORDER BY "TARGET_SET_ID") AS RowNum 
            FROM "SEED"."TT_T_SET_1C8BFA4C_7058" 
            INNER JOIN "SEED"."CELLS" "SUB_CELLS" ON ("SUB_CELLS"."SET_ID"="TT_T_SET_1C8BFA4C_7058"."SOURCE_SET_ID") ) 
            AS SubQuery 
            WHERE SubQuery.RowNum > @startIndex AND SubQuery.RowNum <= (@startIndex + @batchSize) 
            ORDER BY "TARGET_SET_ID"
        SET @startIndex += @batchSize 
    END
```

the execution will not be blocked because the execution plan will use a **Index Seek** on "SETS_U01" **every batch size i use** even if the batch size is greater than the inserted row amount.

- First question: why the index scan is blocked even if the isolation lavel is READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT and the transaction isolation is snapshot?
- Second question: why the batch is working? obviously because it use an index seek. Can i use this batch for every INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM statements?

Table definitions:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [SEED].[SETS](
       [SECT_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
       [SET_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
       [SET_ROW] [int] NOT NULL,
       [META_SET_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [SETS_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   (
       [SECT_ID] ASC,
       [SET_ID] ASC
   )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 90, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [SEED_M01B],
    CONSTRAINT [SETS_U01] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
   (
       [SET_ID] ASC
   )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 90, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [SEED_M01B]
   ) ON [SEED_M01B]
   GO
   CREATE TABLE [SEED].[CELLS](
       [SET_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
       [META_CELL_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [CELLS_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   (
       [SET_ID] ASC,
       [META_CELL_ID] ASC
   )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 90, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [SEED_M01B]
   ) ON [SEED_M01B]
   GO
   ALTER TABLE [SEED].[CELLS]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CELLS_F01] FOREIGN KEY([SET_ID])
   REFERENCES [SEED].[SETS] ([SET_ID])
   GO
```

other table definitions:

```
    CREATE TABLE [SEED].[META_CELLS](
        [UDA_DOMAIN_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [META_DOC_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [META_SECT_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [META_SET_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [META_CELL_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [META_CELL_ROW] [int] NOT NULL,
        [META_CELL_COL] [int] NOT NULL,
        [META_CELL_DESC] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
        [META_CELL_NOTE] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
        [META_CELL_WUOM] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
        [NOT_TRIGGERS_AUDIT] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
        [UDA_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [CEM_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [MCT_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [PUB_ENABLE_ID] [int] NULL,
        [PUB_COLUMN_NAME] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [META_CELLS_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [UDA_DOMAIN_ID] ASC,
        [META_DOC_ID] ASC,
        [META_SECT_ID] ASC,
        [META_SET_ID] ASC,
        [META_CELL_ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 90, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [SEED_M01B],
     CONSTRAINT [META_CELLS_U01] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [META_DOC_ID] ASC,
        [META_SECT_ID] ASC,
        [META_SET_ID] ASC,
        [META_CELL_ROW] ASC,
        [META_CELL_COL] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 90, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [SEED_M01B],
     CONSTRAINT [META_CELLS_U02] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [META_CELL_ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 90, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [SEED_M01B]
    ) ON [SEED_M01B]
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [SEED].[TT_T_SET_1C8BFA4C_7058](
    [SOURCE_SET_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TARGET_SET_ID] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [SEED_U]
GO
```

The point is not the use of transactions. Our transactions can last 1 second or 1 hour. My application manage documents modified by users. And it works well on other databases. I just want to know how to manage this issue or to know if it is unmanageable.
Maybe i have to create indexes in another way or to use table or query hints?
Why i can't insert (in some cases) different records on different tables on different transactions in SQL Server using snapshot isolation?

Comment: `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` still uses pessimistic locking for writes, and foreign-key check always use pessimistic locking whatever you do. Please show the full table and index definitions, and please share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan for further help

Comment: For the not-working query the execution plan is this:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1G6FtJBh

For the working query:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByF8cFyH2

Comment: "I don't want to commit the transactions because the transaction durations are related to users decision"???? Can you elaborate on that part

Comment: It sounds like you're holding database transactions open waiting for use input - *if* that's the case then it's a big design anti-pattern and I would urge a re-think.

Comment: Can we have the definitions for `TT_T_SET_1C8BFA4C_7058` and `META_CELLS` also, and it appears there is a foreign key on `META_CELLS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transaction is being blocked, even under snapshot isolation, because there are foreign keys that need enforcing, and foreign keys are always enforced under `SERIALIZABLE` isolation.

This issue is then exacerbated by the fact that the estimated number of rows is high enough that the server decided to use a merge join, which means it's scanning the full indexes of child tables. This is not necessarily a bad thing in most cases: it's probably a lot faster than loads of index seeks, but it means it's blocking the whole table.

You might be able to force an nested loops/index seek by bringing down the number of estimated rows in the `INSERT`. You can do this in a number of ways:

- Use a plan guide. This can be brittle, as it can depend on the exact query hash, and can disappear if you move servers or database.
- Use `OPTION (LOOP JOIN)`. This can affect the rest of the plan though.
  At the same time, you can use `OFFSET FETCH` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`.

  ```sql
  DECLARE @batchSize bigint = 2000, @offset bigint, @rc bigint;
  WHILE 1=1
  BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO SEED.CELLS WITH (ROWLOCK)
        (SET_ID, META_CELL_ID)
      SELECT
        t.TARGET_SET_ID,
        s.META_CELL_ID
      FROM SEED.TT_T_SET_1C8BFA4C_7058 t
      JOIN SEED.CELLS c ON c.SET_ID = t.SOURCE_SET_ID
      ORDER BY t.TARGET_SET_ID
      OFFSET @offset ROWS
      FETCH NEXT @batchSize ROWS ONLY
      OPTION (LOOP JOIN);

      SET @rc = @@ROWCOUNT;
      SET @offset += @rc;
      IF @rc < @batchSize
          BREAK;
  END;
  ```
- **A better option** is to use `OPTIMIZE FOR` to make the server think it's getting very few rows.

  ```sql
  DECLARE @batchSize bigint = 2000, @offset bigint, @rc bigint;
  WHILE 1=1
  BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO SEED.CELLS WITH (ROWLOCK)
        (SET_ID, META_CELL_ID)
      SELECT
        t.TARGET_SET_ID,
        s.META_CELL_ID
      FROM SEED.TT_T_SET_1C8BFA4C_7058 t
      JOIN SEED.CELLS c ON c.SET_ID = t.SOURCE_SET_ID
      ORDER BY t.TARGET_SET_ID
      OFFSET @offset ROWS
      FETCH NEXT @batchSize ROWS ONLY
      OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@batchSize = 1));

      SET @rc = @@ROWCOUNT;
      SET @offset += @rc;
      IF @rc < @batchSize
          BREAK;
  END;
  ```

  Note that the results are the same, it's just the server has optimized the query thinking that it will *probably* get only one row.

You can obviously do the same thing without batching

```sql
DECLARE @batchSize bigint = 1000000000;

INSERT INTO SEED.CELLS WITH (ROWLOCK)
  (SET_ID, META_CELL_ID)
SELECT TOP (@batchSize)
  t.TARGET_SET_ID,
  s.META_CELL_ID
FROM SEED.TT_T_SET_1C8BFA4C_7058 t
JOIN SEED.CELLS c ON c.SET_ID = t.SOURCE_SET_ID
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@batchSize = 1));
```